# How to export (create a migration) a flatpage (.txt) into a database?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-migrations, django-flatpages

I am using Django and created some flatpages via the admin panel, then I export them to my project in a .txt format using:

```
 python manager.py export_flatpages 1 > my_flat_page.txt
```

Since I am working remotely, I need my peers to be able to quickly migrate those .txt files to their local database.

Any idea about how can I create this migration?

PS>

I already read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/migrations/, but did not get how to relate .txt to migrations.

Comment: Are you sure you used `manage.py export_flatpages` to create the txt file? I'm not aware of this django command. Did you use `dumpdata`?

Comment: Hi, 
Yes, I exported them and saved as separated .txt files. 
The interesting part of this is that it uses an "Django format" (I assume), not json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to export flatpages from your db
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata)

```
python manage.py dumpdata flatpages > flatpages.json
```

And then load this `flatpages.json` using
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/initial-data/)

```
python manage.py loaddata flatpages.json
```

Comment: Indeed this helped me a lot. 
Thank you very much (Y).

Comment: Glad to hear that. If my answer helped, please accept it.

Comment: Sure!, sorry, I think I did yesterday. (Y)